# What is the sum of negative integer powers of all prime numbers?

Tags: prime-numbers, riemann-zeta, moment-generating-functions

The sum of the reciprocals of all primes, $2^{-1}+ 3^{-1}+5^{-1}+7^{-1}+ \cdots$ is infinite,
and  the sum  $2^{-2}+ 3^{-2}+5^{-2}+7^{-2}+ \cdots$ is $0.4522\cdots$  Moreover, $2^{-3}+3^{-3}+5^{-3}+7^{-3}+ \cdots=0.1747\cdots$ etc.   What is known about these numbers?

Comment: Analogous to the usual Riemann zeta function, there’s the prime zeta function ([Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_zeta_function), [MathWorld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeZetaFunction.html)). This includes your cases of interest, so if you investigate further along these lines you’ll presumably find something.

Answer (score 3):

*Coming from my so old cookbook*.

Let
$$S_n=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac 1{p_k^n}=P(n)$$ where $P(n)$ is the  prime zeta function.
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 2 & 0.45224742004106549851 \\
 3 & 0.17476263929944353642 \\
 4 & 0.07699313976424684494 \\
 5 & 0.03575501748392425713 \\
 6 & 0.01707008685063651295 \\
 7 & 0.00828383285613359254 \\
 8 & 0.00406140536651783056 \\
  9 & 0.00200446757496245066 \\
 10 & 0.00099360357443698022 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Have a look [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=DiscretePlot%5BLog%5BPrimeZetaP%5Bn%5D%5D%2C+%7Bn%2C+2%2C+50%7D%5D). If the link is broken, open Wolfram Alpha and enter

`DiscretePlot[Log[PrimeZetaP[n]],{n,2,50}]`

Have also a look at this beautiful [paper](https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/epdf/10.1098/rspl.1881.0063) from year $1882$ and this [one](http://www.17centurymaths.com/contents/euler/introductiontoanalysisvolone/ch15vol1.pdf) by Euler.